# Mutating nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying not to mutate an object within an object before setting it to state like this:

```
isDraggable = () => {
        let steps = [...this.state.stepsData];

        steps = steps.map(step => {
            return {
                ...step,
                dataGrid.static: !step.dataGrid.static 
            }
        });

        this.setState({stepsData: steps})
 };
```

The object structure looks like this:

```
{
 stepsData:[{
  dataGrid: {
   x: ...
   y: ...
   static: true
  }
 }]
}
```

This line  `dataGrid.static: !step.dataGrid.static` doesn't compile. How do I solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't use dot syntax as a property name in an object literal.

Comment: I know! ... thats my question how to make it work.

Comment: Use a nested object? `dataGrid: { static: !step.dataGrid.static }`

Comment: can you maybe make an example? that would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to clone the object `dataGrid` refers to. Also note that you [must use the function callback version of `setState` when you're setting state based on state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous):

```
isDraggable = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        return {stepsData: prevState.steps.map(step => {
            return {
                ...step,
                dataGrid: {...step.dataGrid, static: !step.dataGrid.static}
            };
        })};
    });
};
```

Or more condensed but perhaps less clear:

```
isDraggable = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        stepsData: prevState.steps.map(step => ({
            ...step,
            dataGrid: {...step.dataGrid, static: !step.dataGrid.static}
        }))
    }));
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can overide the `dataGrid` key and spread the `step.dataGrid`

```
isDraggable = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {

        const steps = prevState.stepsData.map(step => {
            return {
                ...step,
                dataGrid: {
                    ...step.dataGrid,
                    static: !step.dataGrid.static
                }
            }
        });

        return { stepsData: steps };
    })
};
```

Comment: You must use the function callback version of `setState` when setting state based on state.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have to unnest each layer of the object you want to change, for example:

```
isDraggable = () => {
  this.setState(state => {
    return state.stepsData.map(step => {
      const { dataGrid } = step;

      return {
        ...step,
        dataGrid: {
          ...dataGrid,
          static: !dataGrid.static
        }
      };
    });
  });
};
```

**EDIT**: changed `setState` to its functional callback form in response to T.J. Crowder's comment.

Comment: You must use the function callback form of `setState` when setting state based on state.